# Deleted all three 'Files' .desktop files in /usr/share/applications/ - how do I get them back?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, nautilus

Whilst trying to fix a bug that gave me two occurrences of the 'Files' shortcut on the dash, one of which would never go away without a reboot, I navigated to `/usr/share/applications/` and deleted all three desktop configuration files titled 'Files'. It turns out that none of these three were identical. One was '`org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`', another was '`nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`', and the last was '`nautilus.desktop`'. I've got no idea which of these were important, but now that they're gone it's broken a few things. How can I get them back?

Comment: I have no special knowledge, but I'd boot a install media (live) for your system and look to see if they were there; if so `cp` & try those.  Otherwise install the release in a VM and `cp` from there (if I didn't have backups or another machine with that release of Ubuntu installed),  If you're patient you may get an easier/faster approach than this dumb-steal hack.

Comment: If you haven't already logged out, run `sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reinstall **nautilus** package with

```
sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus
```

This will give you back the `/usr/share/applications/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop` file. I don't know where the others come from.

Try to look for them with `apt-file`

```
apt-file search /usr/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

and

```
 apt-file search /usr/share/applications/nautilus.desktop
```

Of course, you need **apt-file** installed. `sudo apt install apt-file`

Comment: No luck. "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?"

Comment: Strange, despite having already tried it, sudo apt install --reinstall nautilus has mysteriously solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

All these files came from `nautilus` package. See search results on https://packages.ubuntu.com :

- [`nautilus-folder-handler.desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop)
- [`org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop&searchon=contents)
- [`nautilus.desktop`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=nautilus.desktop)

So you need to reinstall the Nautilus package with:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: No luck. "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?"