# Double Click Not Opening Associated App After Upgrade to 20.04 and Removing Nemo

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 20.04

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and removed Cinnamon and Nemo.

Now, double-clicking files with associated applications does not execute the application, but rather causes Nautilus to refresh.

I made a short [gif demonstrating this](https://gfycat.com/verifiablecookeddove).

Sometimes a new window opens, but most of the time the list just gets refreshed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was libexo that caused this.
I resolved the issue by implementing the solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129510/deleted-all-three-files-desktop-files-in-usr-share-applications-how-do-i)

sudo aptitude search xfce xfd xubuntu | grep ^i|grep A|awk '{print $3}'|xargs sudo apt -y remove
sudo apt -y autoremove